# Model different customers with different interarrival times in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am new to anylogic and trying to model two different customers with different interarrival rates at the source and in service.

I have successfully modelled one customer but having issues with the other. Not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to create 2 sources (and optionally 2 services) and set the different arrival times there.

You can mix'n'match your blocks however you like :)